# What is the correct one to zero or one mapping in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have this model:

```
public class Address
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Street {get; set;}
    public string HouseNo{get; set;}
}

public class Customer
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int AddressId {get; set;}
    public virtual void Address Address {get; set;}
}
```

The current mapping for the `Customer` map is:

```
this.Property(t => t.AddressId).HasColumnName("address_id");

this.HasOptional(t => t.Address)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(d => d.AddressId);
```

There is no mapping back to the `Customer` in the `Address` map.

But this is not working because if I remove the address from the customer, the address record is not deleted from the db.

What is the correct way to add a 1..0-1 relationship where the 0-1 side is owned by the 1 side?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
               .HasOptional(customer => customer.Address)
               .WithRequired()
               .Map(mapping => mapping.MapKey("custom_fk_customer_id"));

   base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Comment: If I do the above, the customer's address property remains null. I guess it doesn't know which foreign key to use.

Comment: If you follow the default naming convention then it finds it?

Comment: I don't follow the default naming convention.

Comment: I see, but if you tried for testing purposes, would it work? Just to give a try and make sure there's no other issue...

Comment: What is the default naming convention then?

Comment: e.g. having a CustomerId column for the foreign key in the Addresses table and having an Id column as the primary key in the Customers table

Comment: Is there an alternative mapping solution to get it to work when not using the default naming conventions?

Comment: I updated the answer. You probably need to add custom mapping as well, as shown in the example.

Comment: In the above model, Customer is the aggregate root, so I changed the mapping to `Map(mapping => mapping.MapKey("address_id")` but then I get an "Invalid column name" exception.

Comment: So, because the Customer is the aggregate root, you have to link the Address to it. In the model (in our case), it means to have the Address property in the Customer, but in the DB schema it has to be linked via the Customers' foreign key, in the Addresses table, right?

Comment: No, in the Db, the customer table as a foreign key 'address_id' and the address only has a primary key 'id'.

Comment: This would allow multiple customers to share the same address on the DB level, right? Is this what you want to achieve?

Comment: This is theoretically possible in the db, but the business logic doesn't allow it. One customer can have 1 unique address or none. If a customer is deleted, his address will be deleted too.

Comment: If you implement it this way, i.e. having foreign key for the Address, then it would mean a "pseudo" one to many relationship from the EF point of view, where the Customer is on the 'many' end. And if you remove the Address from the Customer this would mean that actually one Customer is removed from the customers collection that belongs to the Addess - the 'one' end